# Cloudflare Edge Caching ignoring crawlers

Tags: http, reverse-proxy, cloudflare

I've set up Edge Caching to cache HTML content.  It works perfectly well when resources are hit either by a browser or via Curl.  In both cases, the first request warms the cache and the second request is served directly from Cloudflare.

Through my logs, however, I've noticed that crawlers such as Bing, Yahoo, and Google do not appear to warm the cache.

When I visit urls previously hit by a crawler in the browser or via Curl, that subsequent request hits my origin server as well (according to my server logs).

Is this a matter of plan size (regular vs. Enterprise), bad configuration, or does Cloudflare special case crawler user agents?

Answer (score 0):

If your site isn't visited from the locations Google would ordinarily crawl from, it might not be warm in the CloudFlare Cache.

You might see some benefit from [setting a higher Edge Cache Expire TTL](https://blog.cloudflare.com/edge-cache-expire-ttl-easiest-way-to-override/) in CloudFlare, depending on how frequently search engines crawl your site; in order to do this you need to [use CloudFlare's Page Rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-).

If you want something more bespoke, it's probably best you reach out to [CloudFlare's Enterprise Sales team](https://www.cloudflare.com/enterprise-service-request/).